# What's the minimum float voltage to maintain a small lead-acid battery?

Tags: battery-charging, charging, lead-acid

I wish to 'float' a [**Yuasa Y7-12 7 Ah**](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1524485.pdf), 12V sealed lead acid battery.

On [Battery University](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-403-charging-lead-acid) it says that a voltage of 2.25-2.3 V per cell (so 13.5 - 13.8 V) will allow a lead-acid battery to regulate its own charge current.

What would happen if only 13.0 V was applied? Would this still maintain the battery? My regulated power supply in my home-made alarm project falls a bit short of the recommended 13.5 V so I'm trying to figure out if I need to buy a new one.

Comment: Use 13.7V, it is better on the long run

Comment: 13.0 V is a bit low of a float voltage for a 12 V load-acid battery, but I'm pretty sure it won't *break* anything, at least. Whether it will work or not, I'll leave that up to someone more familiar with the intricacies of lead-acid to answer.

Comment: The battery will maintain full charge or close to full charge at the stated float voltage.    At lower voltages full charge will not be attained. Maintaining voltage above 12.6 V will very greatly reduce sulphation.  (Some sources say 12.4 V, but 12.6 V is safer). Batteries may be discharged to below 12.6 V in use but should be recharged to above this voltage as soon as feasible. || As a comment on a subject far too detailed for a comment: To attain full charge voltage must be held at a higher voltage than float voltage for 12+ hours.

Comment: Edited to add detail. (Was understandable as-was). Removed VTCs

Comment: Can you access the charging circuitry?  Many times, the voltage regulator IC had a resistor pair that controls its output voltage.  There might even be a small potentiometer you can turn to tweak it.